# OpenAPI support for Kotlin router DSL in Springboot2

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

We are moving a codebase to use Kotlin router DSL in a springboot 2 APP. Currently we are using @RestController and kotlin with OpenAPI annotations and this works just fine.

Is anyone aware of any support in the OpenAPI/Swagger annotations for this to work with RouterFunctions DSL?

I using this dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.26</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the springdoc documentation, on the last section, It's mentioned that Spring-weblfux with Functional Endpoints is not yet supported:

- http://springdoc.org/